# Не работает почта в локалке с Centos 6 сервером без организации почтового сервера

Tags: centos

Добрый день. Имеется centos 6 сервер где установлен squid, доступ к интернет через ppp0e. Есть сайт и почтовый сервер на хостинге nic.ru. Есть несколько компьютеров с windows. Получение почты через web на http://www.mail.nic.ru происходит нормально. Нужно настроить получение и отправление почты, пользуясь Thunderbird на этих компьютерах. Как это сделать без создания почтового сервера? Сейчас при попытке получить почту на windows машине Thunderbird пишет: "Найден сервер mail.nic.ru" и на этом все. Если запустить Thunderbird на самом сервере - то все нормально - письма получаю и отправляю.

Comment: Добавить порты в разрешения на сервере.

Comment: Если бы порты были не разрешены, работала бы почта на самом сервере?

Comment: Да вполне, возможен и такой вариант.Я говорю про проброс портов. Понятное дело что приходящие в основном всегда открыты 25 и остальные, а вот из локалки они разрешены? т.е. может ли комп внутри достучаться до 25 порта того же яндекса? ну я про почту. если нет  то проблема на сервере в портах, если да, то копаться в настройках.

Comment: Я понял. Но думаю это решено так:

Comment: -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT  -A FORWARD -i em2 -o em1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT  или ошибаюсь?

Comment: И чем закончилось? что происходит?

Comment: Ответ на вопрос shrekЭто все уже было настроено в IPTABLES до того, как я задал вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Кто мешает использовать для thunderbird проксю? Там в настройках есть вкладка сеть, там прописываете свою проксю и все должно ходить.

**Перенесено из комментария.**

Вот настройки прозрачного прокси (открыт будет только 80 и то только для тех, кому предоставите доступ).

```
iptables -t mangle -Fiptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d "ip провайдера" -j ACCEPTiptables -t mangle -N DIVERTiptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPTiptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERTiptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 3128
```

Comment: Попробовал все настройки TB, в том числе и все варианты прокси. Без результатов.

Comment: Проверьте работу прокси.

Comment: В squid.conf поставил для одной машины access_full - не помогло

Comment: Сбросьте настройки iptabeles  опцией -F и настрой заново. Попробуйте насроить прозрачный прокси!

Comment: Когда перекинул одну машину через НАТ:$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.106 -o $INET_IFACE -j ACCEPT, то на ней почта заработала. Значит проблема в НАТ? Не перекидывать же все машины - тогда зачем было огород городить.

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.